# Powershell Out-file not working

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script which gathers some file information on some remote servers.
When writing to the console, I see the results just fine, but they don't seem to be getting written into the specified out-file:

```
out-file -filepath $filepath -inputobject $date -force -encoding ASCII -width 50
ForEach($server in $serverLists)
{
$result += $server
$result += $break

ForEach($filePath in $filePaths)
{
    $result += $filePath
    $result += $break

    $command = "forfiles /P " + $filePath + " /S /D -1 > C:\temp\result.txt"
    $cmd = "cmd /c $command"

    Invoke-WmiMethod -class Win32_process -name Create -ArgumentList $cmd -ComputerName $server
    sleep 2
    $result += Get-Content \\$server\C$\temp\result.txt
    $result += $break
    $result += $break
    write-host $result
    #out-file -filepath $filepath -Append -inputobject $result -encoding ASCII -width 200
    Remove-Item \\$server\C$\temp\result.txt
}
$result += $break
}

out-file -filepath $filepath -Append -inputobject $result -encoding ASCII -width 200
```

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you working with?

Comment: You use `$filepath` as loop variable for inner `foreach` loop. You also use `$filepath` variable before outer `foreach` loop. Should it be two different variables with different names?

Comment: @PetSerAl, that was the issue (I thought variables were case sensitive)
please make a response so I may mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use same variable `$filepath` in two places: as loop variable for `foreach` loop and outside of loop. `foreach` loop does not restore value of loop variable after loop ends. So, right after loop ends loop variable will have last value of loop or value where loop was interrupted by `break` command. If you does not want variable value to be overwritten by `foreach` loop, then you should choose different name for loop variable.